# Multi-threaded parallelism performance problem with Fibonacci sequence in Julia (1.3)

Tags: multithreading, julia, fibonacci

I'm trying the multithread function of `Julia 1.3` with the following Hardware:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Processor Name: Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:    2.8 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  4
L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
L3 Cache:   6 MB
Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
Memory: 16 GB
```

When running the following script:

```
function F(n)
if n < 2
    return n
    else
        return F(n-1)+F(n-2)
    end
end
@time F(43)
```

it gives me the following output

```
2.229305 seconds (2.00 k allocations: 103.924 KiB)
433494437
```

However when running the following code copied from the [Julia page about multithreading](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/07/multithreading)

```
import Base.Threads.@spawn

function fib(n::Int)
    if n < 2
        return n
    end
    t = @spawn fib(n - 2)
    return fib(n - 1) + fetch(t)
end

fib(43)
```

what happens is that the utilisation of RAM/CPU jumps from 3.2GB/6% to 15GB/25% without any output (for at least 1 minute, after which i decided to kill the julia session)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21):

Great question.

This multithreaded implementation of the Fibonacci function is *not* faster than the single threaded version. That function was only shown in the blog post as a toy example of how the new threading capabilities work, highlighting that it allows for spawning many many threads in different functions and the scheduler will figure out an optimal workload.

The problem is that `@spawn` has a non-trivial overhead of around `1µs`, so if you spawn a thread to do a task that takes less than `1µs`, you've probably hurt your performance. The recursive definition of `fib(n)` has exponential time complexity of order `1.6180^n` [1], so when you call `fib(43)`, you spawn something of order `1.6180^43` threads. If each one takes `1µs` to spawn, it'll take around 16 minutes just to spawn and schedule the needed threads, and that doesn't even account for the time it takes to do the actual computations and re-merge / sync threads which takes even more time.

Things like this where you spawn a thread for each step of a computation only make sense if each step of the computation takes a long time compared to the `@spawn` overhead.

Note that there is work going into lessening the overhead of `@spawn`, but by the very physics of multicore silicon chips I doubt it can ever be fast enough for the above `fib` implementation.

---

If you're curious about how we could modify the threaded `fib` function to actually be beneficial, the easiest thing to do would be to only spawn a `fib` thread if we think it will take significantly longer than `1µs` to run. On my machine (running on 16 physical cores), I get

```
function F(n)
    if n < 2
        return n
    else
        return F(n-1)+F(n-2)
    end
end


julia> @btime F(23);
  122.920 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

so thats a good two orders of magnitude over the cost of spawning a thread. That seems like a good cutoff to use:

```
function fib(n::Int)
    if n < 2
        return n
    elseif n > 23
        t = @spawn fib(n - 2)
        return fib(n - 1) + fetch(t)
    else
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    end
end
```

now, if I follow proper benchmark methodology with BenchmarkTools.jl [2] I find

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime fib(43)
  971.842 ms (1496518 allocations: 33.64 MiB)
433494437

julia> @btime F(43)
  1.866 s (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
433494437
```

---

@Anush asks in the comments: This is a factor of 2 speed up using 16 cores it seems. Is it possible to get something closer to a factor of 16 speed up?

Yes it is. The problem with the above function is that the function body is larger than that of `F`, with lots of conditionals, function / thread spawning and all that. I invite you to compare `@code_llvm F(10)` `@code_llvm fib(10)`. This means that `fib` is much harder for julia to optimize. This extra overhead  it makes a world of difference for the small `n` cases.

```
julia> @btime F(20);
  28.844 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime fib(20);
  242.208 μs (20 allocations: 320 bytes)
```

Oh no! all that extra code that never gets touched for `n < 23` is slowing us down by an order of magnitude! There's an easy fix though: when `n < 23`, don't recurse down to `fib`, instead call the single threaded `F`.

```
function fib(n::Int)
    if n > 23
       t = @spawn fib(n - 2)
       return fib(n - 1) + fetch(t)
    else
       return F(n)
    end
end

julia> @btime fib(43)
  138.876 ms (185594 allocations: 13.64 MiB)
433494437
```

which gives a result closer to what we'd expect for so many threads.

[1] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-recursive-fibonacci-program/

[2] The BenchmarkTools `@btime` macro from BenchmarkTools.jl will run functions multiple times, skipping the compilation time and average results.

Comment: This is a factor of 2 speed up using 16 cores it seems. Is it possible to get something closer to a factor of 16 speed up?

Comment: Use a larger base case. BTW, this is how effectively multithreaded programs like FFTW work under the hood as well!

Comment: Larger base case doesn't help. The trick is that `fib` is harder for julia to optimize than `F`, so we just use `F` instead of `fib` for `n< 23`. I edited my answer with a more indepth explanation and example.

Comment: That's weird, I actually got better results using the blog post example...

Comment: @tpdsantos What is the output of `Threads.nthreads()` for you? I suspect you might have julia running with only a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

@Anush

As an example of using memoization and multithreading manually

```
_fib(::Val{1}, _,  _) = 1
_fib(::Val{2}, _, _) = 1

import Base.Threads.@spawn
_fib(x::Val{n}, d = zeros(Int, n), channel = Channel{Bool}(1)) where n = begin
  # lock the channel
  put!(channel, true)
  if d[n] != 0
    res = d[n]
    take!(channel)
  else
    take!(channel) # unlock channel so I can compute stuff
    #t = @spawn _fib(Val(n-2), d, channel)
    t1 =  _fib(Val(n-2), d, channel)
    t2 =  _fib(Val(n-1), d, channel)
    res = fetch(t1) + fetch(t2)

    put!(channel, true) # lock channel
    d[n] = res
    take!(channel) # unlock channel
  end
  return res
end

fib(n) = _fib(Val(n), zeros(Int, n), Channel{Bool}(1))


fib(1)
fib(2)
fib(3)
fib(4)
@time fib(43)


using BenchmarkTools
@benchmark fib(43)
```

But the speed up came from memmiozation and not so much multithreading. Lesson here is that we should think better algorithms before multithreading.

Comment: The question was never about computing Fibonacci numbers fast. The point was 'why isn't multithreading improving this naïve implementation?'.

Comment: For me, the next logical question is: how to make it fast. So someone reading this can see my solution and learn from it, perhaps.